# Twitter APIs : update working, but filter does not

Tags: javascript, oauth, twitter

Twitter APIs : update working, but filter does not
javascript twitter oauth twitter-api jsoauth

In the following code, I instantiate an instance of `OAuth` from the jsOAuth library by bytespider

```
    // jsoauth API reference:
    // http://bytespider.github.com/jsOAuth/api-reference/

    var twitter = new OAuth(oauthOptions);

    //authentication occurs

    console.log('url: ' + url);
    console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));

    twitter.post(
        url,
        data,
        success,
        failure
    );
```

When I access the stream:

```
    url: https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json 
    data: {"track":"%40twitterapi"} 
    --> This does not work, neither the `success` nor `failure` callbacks get called, just hangs
```

When I tweet:

```
    url: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json 
    data: {"status":"foobar","trim_user":true,"include_entities":true} 
    --> This works, the `success` callback gets called
```

My guess is that the authentication details are not getting through to the `stream.twitter.com` API, even though it get through to the `api.twitter.com` API. Can safely rule out OAuth issues as being able to tweet demonstrates that authentication has succeeded.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that

> This does not work, neither the `success` nor `failure` callbacks get
>   called, just hangs

because you are using the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis), which was meant to "hang", as using this means that you are opening a connection to Twitter's servers that will be kept alive as long as the application is running. Every new tweet will be then sent to this connection in realtime like water through a pipe.

You should look into using [HTML5 WebSockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/).

Comment: +1 && check @ Arvin : Didn't think that it was streaming in that sense, because it appears under their 'REST API' section ( https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api ). Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @ Arvin : I have asked a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374771/how-to-make-twitter-streaming-apis-work-with‌​-jsoauth If you know how to do this with HTML5 WebSockets, and would like to show how, that would be excellent!