# How to make Twitter Streaming APIs work with jsOAuth?

Tags: javascript, twitter, streaming, jsoauth

As has been noted in the answer to my prior question:
[Twitter APIs : update working, but filter does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372835/twitter-apis-update-working-but-filter-does-not)

.. the `filter` API is a streaming API:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis

I would like to make jsOAuth work with these streaming APIs:
https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth

It works well with the REST APIs, and if anyone has made (or knows how to make) it work with the streaming APIs, please enlighten me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsOauth does **not** currently support streaming API, as confirmed by its own author:

https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth/issues/29#issuecomment-6841882

Looks like I will have to find an alternative till the next release.